# Typescript project to productive use

Tags: node.js, typescript, deployment

I want to create a project with expressjs in typescript.
I know expressjs and i know typescript, but my question is how can i bring my project to productive use?

Do i publish my raw typescript files? But then i have to install a typescript transpiler on every server and i'm not able to run the project with "plain" nodejs.

Or do i transpile my typescript files? But then normaly the javascript files will be created in a subfolder like "build". When i deploy the whole "buil" folder the dependencies are missing and i can't run "npm install" because the build folder has no package.json.

I'm not happy with both methods. So how do you handle typescript projects and bring them up tp production?

Comment: I haven't heard of any servers interpreting typescript directly on the fly; typically you transpile to js and make that work; if you're having issues with missing dependencies then that's a separate issue to do with how things are being built

Comment: When i transpile my .ts files the .js files will be created in the "outdir" folder. But there is no package.json so i can't install the dependecies on the server with "npm install". So what's the correct workflow to ship a typescript project?